# Iterar sobre keys

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Estoy intentando imprimir los nombres de los campos de una tabla en un componente de `vue` desde una array que tengo creada en mi `main.js`;

Tengo la siguiente array:

```
tabla2: [
    { STAT: "ON", DESC: "DESCRIPTION", HDD: "100%"},
    { STAT: "OFF", DESC: "DESCRIPTION", HDD: "65%"},
   ]
```

Y el siguiente getter:

```
getters: {
        columnas: state => {
            return state.tabla2.keys()
        }
}
```

Estos datos los he imprimido en mi componente, pero no las keys de cada campo. En el componente he importado el getter:

```
<script>
import {mapGetters} from 'vuex'

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters([
      'columnas'
    ])
  }
}
</script>
```

Para imprimir los nombres de los campos, he intentado recorrer los valores de la array con un `v-if` usando la `key`:

```
<b-thead>
    <b-tr v-for="a in columnas" :key="a">
        <b-th> {{a}} </b-th>
    </b-tr>
</b-thead>
```

Alguna idea de como mostrar los "titulos" en la tabla?

Comment: Si, eso intento obtener. No he conseguido nada añadiendo el [0]

Comment: Genial! Me imprime los elementos de la array pero en la misma columna de la tabla (en la primera). Miraré que puede ser esto, gracias!!

Comment: Eso era, gracias de nuevo!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como mencionas, en el state tienes el siguiente array de objetos:

```
tabla2: [
    { STAT: "ON", DESC: "DESCRIPTION", HDD: "100%"},
    { STAT: "OFF", DESC: "DESCRIPTION", HDD: "65%"},
]
```

Y quieres obtener las keys de uno de los objetos

```
['STAT', 'DESC', 'HDD']
```

Para usarlas como títulos de una tabla en el template

```
<b-thead>
    <b-tr>
        <b-th v-for="a in columnas" :key="a"> {{a}} </b-th>
    </b-tr>
</b-thead>
```

Entonces, en el `getter`, podrías que acceder a uno de los objetos (por ejemplo el primero, que tendría el índice `0`). A esto lo logras [accediendo a un elemento de Array mediante su índice](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array):

```
state.tabla2[0]
```

Y de ese objeto obtener las `keys`. A esto lo logras con [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```
Object.keys(state.tabla2[0])
```

Finalmente tu `getter` podría quedar de la siguiente manera:

```
getters: {
    columnas: state => {
        return Object.keys(state.tabla2[0])
    }
}
```